# SELECT where date = current date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following code which should select a row from my DB with the current day's date.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Forecast WHERE date(epoch) LIKE '". $mysqldate . "';";

        echo $sql . "\n";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

            $pop = 0;

            $forecast = new DailyForecast($row->epoch, ...);

            return $forecast;
        }
        else {
            echo "no data found..\n";
        }
```

Running `SELECT * FROM Forecast WHERE date(epoch) LIKE '2015-11-03'` in PHPmyAdmin works fine. In my script it return false or nothing...

Comment: Add or die(mysqli_error($db)); at the end of your mysqli_query and post the error. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition looks like it's the wrong way round.

```
if (!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
```

So if there's no result or no rows, you start executing code that seems to expect rows. However if there is a result or there are rows you echo 'no data found'
Try this instead:

```
if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```